# Is it possible to center a map at a fixed position (lat lng) - 100px?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I mean, I'd like to center a map to a fixed position :

```
map.setCenter(markerCliccato.getPosition());
```

and less (Y-axis) 100px down. Is it possible? Or I need the Lat/Lng of this "virtual" point?

This is because I have a InfoWindow very height, and I need to put it 100px from top of the map! Can't use "margin" on infowindow because can make troubles with other marker in the map.

**Example**

I have this point as Lat/Lng : https://maps.google.com/?q=54.572062,-3.038818

But I want to center the map at https://maps.google.com/?q=54.486793,-3.042046 (which is more or less 100px down of my point, in the map)

Comment: Me too, I'm Italian! I mean : I can center the map due to the Lat Lng of a marker, right? Well! Now move the map 100px down, with cursor! The center of the map should be what I'm looking for...

Comment: No : I don't mean "move the map", but move the centering of the map down of 100px...

Comment: Check the Example, maybe it will be more clear...

Comment: ok. updated my demo on jsfiddle. click the button to center 100 px down. if it works ill post as an answer. http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/

Comment: I don't see any marker on your example :O Also, ok, it move the map "down", but of course it must be rendered on top, not gray :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i need to post pictures :)

this is before the click

[image: before]

and this is after

[image: after]

there is no gray area, the map is all rendered.

also, to see the marker you must allow the site to track your location.

```
function offsetCenter(latlng, offsetx, offsety) {
    var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
    var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(
    map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());

    var worldCoordinateCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
    var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point((offsetx / scale) || 0, (offsety / scale) || 0)

    var worldCoordinateNewCenter = new google.maps.Point(
    worldCoordinateCenter.x - pixelOffset.x, worldCoordinateCenter.y + pixelOffset.y);

    var newCenter = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinateNewCenter);

    map.setCenter(newCenter);
}
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/

*tested with FF 15, IE 9 and Chrome 21*