# How can I center a map due to the InfoWindow center?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to center a map at a fixed position (lat lng) - 100px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234295/is-it-possible-to-center-a-map-at-a-fixed-position-lat-lng-100px)

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/VFqm5/) :

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.745334,12.738430);
var options = { zoom: 12, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map, title: 'Example' });   

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var window_content = '<div style="width:110px;height:150px;">Test</div>';
infoWindow.setContent(window_content);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

As you can see the map is centered by "position Marker", not by InfoWindow height.
I need to have in the center of the map the center of the infowindow, in less words.

How can I do it?

P.S. I want to avoid the workaround to put an "high margin-top" at the infowindow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to actually recenter the marker, not the infowindow.

did you manage to see the marker on the last example i gave you?

if so, when you drag it, you will see that the marker is re-centered with the infowindow.

here i added your infowindow html to it: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/10/

```
<div style="width:110px;height:150px;">Test</div>
```

[image: 150px]

and here a 250 px high infowindow

[image: 250px]

### EDIT

here is the last part of your code updated:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var window_content = '<div style="width:110px;height:200px;">Test</div>';
infoWindow.setContent(window_content);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
});
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/VFqm5/1/

Comment: Yeah, but it depends : some infowindow are 150 height, some 250...who knows? :)

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't need this :) I need that InfoWindow is always centered in the map, not with an offset of 100px from the top...

Comment: @markzzz: i am not using the offset code. forget about the button. just drag the marker to see the infowindow auto-center in the map.

Comment: @markzzz: maybe you're new to this and i assumed, looking at your 4.6k rep, that you would be able to adapt my code to your need. sorry about that. i updated my answer just using **your code**.

Comment: map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()),

This helped me. Thanks!