# Google Maps API - Create Offset for Overlays dynamical for every zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a `balloon` which pops up when clicking on a `Marker`. Sometimes the balloon exeeds the bounds of the map and is not fully shown.

I can't center the map to the coordinates of the marker, because the ballon is sometimes too high and would still be outside the bounds. So I need an `offset` which moves the center of the map slightly down so the balloon is always nicly in the middle of my map.

The problem is that Google maps doesn't work with pixels but with `LatLng`. Therefore I need a dynamically scalable function to keep the offset in every zoomlevel the same!

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13234921/982924

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center a map at a fixed position (lat lng) - 100px?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234295/is-it-possible-to-center-a-map-at-a-fixed-position-lat-lng-100px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found an algorithmic solution!

```
map.setCenter(
 new google.maps.LatLng(
  marker.getPosition().lat()+(X/Math.pow(2,map.getZoom())),
  marker.getPosition().lng()
 )
);
```

Each zoom level nearly doubles the LatLng which is shown on the map. So just find an `X` which is the perfect offset for you (in my case it was 128) and everything works great!

PS: The position of the marker is the same as the balloon.

Comment: You found your solution 0 minutes after posting your question?

Comment: @Marcelo - This is fine in this case as far as I am aware. Others may encounter the same problem in the future and now the information is on this site for reference. See here for more info - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/201262

Comment: @Marcelo: There is a Q&A option when posting a question. You are aware of this, are you? :)